# How to save intensity value without loosing precision of image data in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

Lets say we have a simple RGB image on disk.

If we read the image using `imread()` it gets stored as `uint8` type. Then I do Discrete Fourier Transform on it using `fft()`, the returned image is of `double` type.

Now, on storing this data as image on disk, using `imwrite()`, and again read using `imread()`, the precision of data seems to get lost and again the image is stored as `uint8`.

This means, I can't operate Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform on saved DFT image! How should I approach this one?

Comment: Save it in a different format, perhaps as a .csv file or a simple .mat file? Look at `save` and `csvwrite`.

Comment: can't I save as image and get back?

Comment: Why? Just save it as a `.mat` file, and if you want an image to look at save a separate image. That way it doesn't matter that it's `uint8`

Comment: @Surya correct me if I'm wrong, but the `double` image you get after `fft` has complex values. How are you planning on storing and restoring them?

Comment: @Shai, if the image is symmetric, the FFT could be real.

Comment: @tashuhka how many symmetric images do you know? like really really symmetric to numerical precision?

Comment: @Shai. Sorry to insist, but a variable with Hermitian symmetry has a real valued Fourier Transform (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/why-is-the-fft-mirrored).  It is totally true that the limited numerical precision of most machines will make it hard to achieve in real application with real images. But mathematically or with ideal cases it is possible: `Yreal = fft2(ones(100));` `Ycomplex = fft2(eye(100));`.

Comment: @tashuhka of course you are correct, I do not argue with the theory of FFT. But this question deals with real images with FFT computed on a real computer... I do not think it is likely that the images in question are Hermitian symmteric...

Comment: @Shai. True. With the appropriate argumentation, both of us are right. Isn't it great? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an file format that supports floating point images. Tiff is one of them. imwrite doesn't have the flexibility so you need to use the Tiff class. This will not work with complex data. If it's complex I would use matlabs mat format.

```
function imwriteDouble(filename,data)
% imwriteDouble(filename,data) saves floating point data in tiff image
n=ndims(data);
t=Tiff(filename,'w'); 
tagstruct.ImageLength = size(data,1);
tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(data,2);
tagstruct.BitsPerSample = 64;
if n==2
   tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 1;
   tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack;
elseif n == 3
   tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 3;
   tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.RGB;
else
   error('Image must have 2 or 3 dimensions');
end
tagstruct.Compression=Tiff.Compression.None;
tagstruct.SampleFormat=Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP;
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;
t.setTag(tagstruct); 
t.write(data);
t.close();
end
```

You can read the image back using `imread`.